# WPF Datagrid scrollbar does not appear

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

This is my XAML code:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" MaxWidth="2048" MinWidth="989" Width="Auto" x:Name="dockPanelGrid" Grid.Column="2"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="top" Background="Red">
    <DataGrid x:Name="GridData" MaxWidth="2048" IsReadOnly="True" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
        SelectionMode="Extended" 
        SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
        Style="{StaticResource DataGridStatStyle}" 
        DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
        Margin="0" 
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="false" 
        VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item" 
        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" 
        EnableRowVirtualization="false" 
        EnableColumnVirtualization="False" 
        CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
        Loaded="GridData_Loaded">
    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

I noticed that when I have no records bound to the DataGrid, the last columns are not shown and scrollbar does not appear. If I have at least one row, everything works fine.
In order to be sure about the size of my DataGrid and its container I wrote this:

```
double antani = 0;
foreach (DataGridColumn col in GridData.Columns)
    antani += col.ActualWidth;

if (antani > GridData.ActualWidth)
    ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(dockPanelGrid, ScrollBarVisibility.Visible);
else
    ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(dockPanelGrid, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
```

And I see that antani (which is the "real" width of Datagrid) is greater that the container, but I'm not be able to show the horiziontal scrollbar. Any help?

Comment: Why is there a dockpanel there at all? Why not just put the datagrid directly in the grid if its the only thing in the cell?

Comment: Correct, I will try to remove it but I do not think is up to that

Comment: If the width is bigger than the container that means something is telling the datagrid it can have as much space as it likes. Removing the dockpanel narrows down what is causing the issue. In any case. Having a pointless panel as a container is not a good thing.

Comment: I removed the DockPanel and adapted the code. But what drive me crazy is that this issue raise up only without records; if I add at least one all works fine.
Seems that the size of headers are not cosindered in terms of scrollbar visibility

Comment: @PIKOT Does this happen when you bind a an empty collection or only when you bind no `ItemsSource` at all?

Comment: @thatguy when my collection is empty I do not bind anything, so the ItemSource is null

Comment: How does it know what columns it will have? You don't have any columns in that markup.

Comment: I add them in code behind since my collection could be dynamic in terms of column number